# How can I route user logins to their account?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, user-accounts

I need to be be pointed to the right direction.  I am writing a simple application where a user can log in and see their task list.  I want the app secure.  I can only get as far as authenticating a user to access the entire site.  Obviously that's not what I want.  I want them to access ONLY their own accounts.  Is there a good site to read about this?  I'm learning v2.x .  Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code and a specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not think of any site other than the book. That is how I implemented mine. I set the logged user in app controller's beforeRender callback. That way it is available in all controllers.

I then have a function in the users controller called dashboard

```
function dashboard($userId = NULL) {}
```

If the userId matches the one in the logged user, or in my case, the user is an admin, then proceed, else redirect the user with a message that they are not permitted.

All of this is if you are using only the Auth component. If you want to use the ACL component too, you will have to check if the user is also permitted to access the page.

Sources
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty general, but here's some info that might help.

With regrards to listing and viewing data, you have access to the logged in users ID. So, throughout your app, in all methods, just fetch data that relates to the logged in users ID.

With regards to editing/deleting data, you may need to check the logged in user's ID against the ID of the record they are trying to edit or delete.

Here's some old CakePHP 1.3 (ie, NOT 2.x) code I dug up. This method was in my AppController, and was called when a user tries to edit/delete a record, to make sure that record belongs to their user account.

```
function checkUserID($pUserId) {
    // This is called for methods when a user can only access it for their own user account - eg, a user can call 'edit', but only on their own records.    
    if ($pUserId != $this->Auth->user('id')){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to access that location', true));
        $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }
}
```

To give an example of how this method is used, when a user tries to delete a comment in that app, I do the following:

```
$commentToDelete = $this->Comment->read(null, $id); // get the comment they are trying to delete
$this->checkUserID($commentToDelete['Comment']['user_id']); // check that it is their own comment
// If they pass the above test, then continue and delete the comment.
// If not, they will have already been redirected by the checkUserID method
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

EDIT:
In response to Nick's comment below:

I've used isAuthorized() before, but can't see how it would work in the example I gave above. If the user's deleting a comment, you have to do this:

```
$this->checkUserID($commentToDelete['Comment']['user_id']); // check that it is their own comment
```

But if they're deleting a widget, it would have to be:

```
$this->checkUserID($widgetToDelete['Widget']['user_id']); // check that it is their own widget
```

The situation could be even more complex if, eg, they are editing a 'photo' record, that belongs to a 'gallery' record, that holds their user_id, so the 'photo' record itself doesn't have a 'user_id' field.

I can't see how you'd be able to handle these possible situations gracefully in isAuthorized(). Am I missing something? I guess the question is, in isAuthorized(), you can get the ID of the logged in user, but how do you know which other ID to compare it with, to make sure the record they are editing or deleting belongs to them?

Comment: This should work however Cake has a built in Authentication system that will handle this without having to reinvent the wheel and write your own function.

Comment: OK cool. Could you explain that a little more? Got a link to an appropriate cookbook page or something? Or could you add it as a separate answer to this question? I hate re-inventing wheels! Thanks.

Comment: There is an isAuthorized(); callback method defined here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-controllerauthorize

Comment: I can't see how isAuthorized would work. I've made an edit to the last part of my answer... can you read it and let me know what you think? If isAuthorized can work, I'd love to know how. Feel free to edit my answer as typing code in comments is annoying. Cheers.

Comment: I was mistaken, I misread your answer, isAuthorized() doesn't seem like it would work in this situation because it's only passed the user object, my mistake :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain of what you're asking but from what I understand you need your users to have access to some sort of control panel or interface that pertains to their accounts only. Here's what I would do to achieve this:

- Set up a function in your controller that takes no parameters
- Check to make sure a user is logged in
- If they are then set the data you need to the view while using the
  user's id field as a condition. Using this method the user can not
  specify what data they're trying to acces, it is up to the logic in
  your controller and models
- If they are not then redirect them somewhere else

If you edit your question and provide some more information on what you're trying to accomplish I can give you an example or explain further.

Comment: [link](http://bit.ly/Mk0Iyb)  So I have created a login.  When a user enters at this point, can access all of the information.  I want them to only access their own folders and not the folders others have created.  I was thinking of adding a folders foreign key to the users table.  But I still don't really understand how to connect the folders the the users ID.

Comment: username and password is: test